# Getting Get-Help Parameters as C# objects

Tags: c#, powershell

I am calling `Get-Help ... -Full` on various scripts to determine what Parameters are needed to run the script. A dynamic form is then displayed for the user to fill out.

I've noticed that `Get-Help` does not always return the same structure, i.e some scripts return

```
NAME
    ....

SYNOPSIS

SYNTAX
    ....

DESCRIPTION
    ...

PARAMETERS
```

while others simply return

```
test2.ps1 [[-foo] <String>] [[-bar] <String>]
```

I started down a path to retrieve this information from the `PSObject`:

```cs
PSObject p = (PSObject)results[0].Properties["Parameters"].Value;

foreach (var info in p.Properties)
{
    var b = (PSObject[])info.Value;
    foreach ( var c in b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.Properties["name"].Value);
    }
}
```

But this fails with the second type of result.

Is there not a more common way to retrieve this information that I have overlooked?

Comment: The difference in output is because the scripts showing extended information have [comment-based help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458353.aspx) while the others just have [`[CmdletBindings()]`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14671051/1630171) enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the output from `Get-Command -Syntax`

[image: test2 syntax]

You can retrieve this information in C# by creating a `CommandInfo` object and accessing the `Parameters` and `ParameterSets` properties:

```
CommandInfo getHelpCommand = new CmdletInfo("Get-Help", typeof(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand));
var Params = getHelpCommand.Parameters;

foreach (string paramKey in Params.Keys)
{
    ParameterMetadata currentParam = Params[paramKey];
    Console.Write(currentParam.Name);
}
```

Comment: +1 for directing me to the Get-Command -Syntax, this at least returns me predictable results. I'm confused on the CmdletInfo however. I can't seem to figure out how to actually use it.

Comment: The items in the `Parameters` and `ParameterSets` dictionaries contain information about whether each parameter is mandatory, what type it expects etc. My point being that you could use this information to determine what the syntax is, and generate your own `Command-Name [[-Parameter] <type>]`-style string