# Powershell - pass a value to parameter

Tags: powershell

How to pass value along with parameter? Something like .`/test.ps1 -controllers 01`. I want the script to use `hyphen` and also a value is passed along for the parameter.

Here is the part of the script I wrote. But if I call the script with `hyphen` (`.\test.ps1 -Controllers`) it says `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Controllers'.`

```
param(
   # [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=0)]
    [ValidateSet('Controllers','test2','test3')]
    [String]$options

)
```

Also I need to pass a value to it which is then used for a property.

```
if ($options -eq "controllers")
{
   $callsomething.$arg1 | where {$_ -eq "$arg2" }
}
```

Comment: That would be either `.\test.ps1 -options Controllers` or `.\test.ps1 Controllers`

Comment: Okay what about passing a value? Should I create another param for $arg2? or is there another way?

Comment: Read up on the [CmdLetBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7) attribute.  You can add this attribute to a function or to a script file.  Once you do that,  you can call the function or script file using the same syntax you use with built in cmdlets.  This includes passing parameters by name or by position.

Comment: Also, check out [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671051/what-is-cmdletbinding-and-how-does-it-work).

Answer (score 0):

Lets talk about why it does not work

```
function Test()
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=0)]
        [ValidateSet('Controllers','test2','test3')]
        [String]$options
    )
}
```

**Parameters** are Variables that are created and filled out at the start of the script

`ValidateSet` will only allow the script to run if `$Options` equals one of the three choices `'Controllers','test2','test3'`

Lets talk about what exactly all the `[]` are doing

`Mandatory=$false` means that `$options` doesnt have to be anything in order for the script to run.

`Position=0` means that if you entered the script without using the `-options` then the very first thing you put would still be options

Example

```
#If Position=0 then this would work
Test "Controllers"
#Also this would work
Test -options Controllers
```

`[ValidateSet('Controllers','test2','test3')]` means that if Option is used or is `Mandatory` then it has to equal `'Controllers','test2','test3'`

It sounds like you are trying to create parameters at runtime. Well that is possible using `DynamicParam`.

```
function Test{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    DynamicParam {
        $Parameters  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        'Controllers','test2','test3' | Foreach-object{
            $Param  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $Param.Mandatory  = $false
            $AttribColl = New-Object  System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $AttribColl.Add($Param)
            $RuntimeParam  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("$_",  [string], $AttribColl)
            $Parameters.Add("$_",  $RuntimeParam) 
        }
        return $Parameters
    }
    begin{
        $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{
            Set-Variable $_.Key -Value $_.Value
        } 
    }
    process {

        "$Controllers $Test2 $Test3"

    }
}
```

DynamicParam allows you to create parameters in code. 
The example above turns the array `'Controllers','test2','test3'` into 3 separate parameters.

```
Test -Controllers "Hello" -test2 "Hey" -test3 "Awesome"
```

returns

```
Hello Hey Awesome
```

But you said you wanted to keep the hypen and the parameter

So the line

```
$PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable $_.Key -Value $_.Value
}
```

allows you to define each parameter value. a slight change like :

```
$PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable $_.Key -Value "-$($_.Key) $($_.Value)"
}
```

Would return

```
-Controllers Hello -test2 Hey -test3 Awesome
```