# How CmdletBinding() on top of a .ps1 file works?

Tags: powershell

Considering the PowerShell code example [here](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Azure-AD-B2C-Series-Custom-Policies-Release-Automation-with-Azure-DevOps/):

[image: powershell code]

It has `[CmdletBinding()]` on top of the .ps1 scipt file.

**Please note that** [CmdletBinding()] is on top of the file, not the function.

How do I call this file from commandline and assign values to the parameters?

What is the name of this technique, so I can search and learn more about the concept?

Comment: `help about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute` ?

Comment: That just means you can call the file name like a function. ex: `file.ps1 -param1 "Hello World"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \[cmdletbinding()\] and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671051/what-is-cmdletbinding-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Think of a file as a large function with a file extension, you can assign parameters to a file with `param` just like you can with a function, with that you can also use `[cmdletbinding()]` on files just like you can in functions.

Comment: @NekoMusume, thanks. Please add your answer so I can mark is as answer.

Comment: @JosefZ, not it doesn't. consider my comment "Please note that [CmdletBinding()] is on top of the file, not the function.". Neko answered my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of a file as a large function with a file extension, you can assign parameters to a file with `param` just like you can with a function, with that you can also use `[CmdletBinding()]` on files just like you can in functions. For example, if I have a file that has multiple switches and can take arguments I could do something like

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param([switch]$a,
      [string]$b)
if ($a) {return Write-Host $b -ForegroundColor red}
return Write-Host $b
```

Would be the same as doing

```
function MyName {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([switch]$a
        [string]$b)
    if ($a) {return Write-Host $b -ForegroundColor red}
    return Write-Host $b
}
```

and you could call them with

```
#file
.\MyName.ps1 -a -b Test
```

or

```
#function
MyName -a -b Test
```

and they will have the same output., a red `Test`

Unlike batch files (`.bat`) you cannot directly call a `ps1` script just with its name, so just using `MyName -a -b Test` without the function being defined will result in an error.